# Does ansible actually use 'include' as keyword?

Tags: ansible

I inherited a playbook like file `thing.yaml` with the following content:

```
---
- include: one.yaml
- include: two.yaml
```

I usually launch the yaml files with `ansible-playbook` as I can do with `one.yaml` and `two.yaml`, but `thing.yaml` is rejected with:

```
ERROR! 'include' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '.../thing.yaml': line 2, column 3, but
may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- include: one.yaml
  ^ here
```

Which command line is going to eat files with includes like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` module has been deprecated with `ansible` version 2.16, because

> it has too many conflicting behaviours depending on keyword combinations and it was unclear how it should behave in each case. new actions were developed that were specific about each case and related behaviours.

[Source: Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html)

The alternatives are [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html), [`import_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html) and [`import_playbook`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html). (My personal guess is [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html) too but it's not listed.)

Comment: `import_playbook` it is

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `include_tasks`, not `include`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/include_tasks_module.html

Comment: So you bet that that file never worked before?

Comment: On the contrary, I bet that file worked in previous versions of Ansible. I think it changed from "include" to "include_tasks" round the 2.2 release, I can't remember exactly.

Comment: `ERROR! 'include_tasks' is not a valid attribute for a Play`